# An error occured in MOVEIT: ABORTED: START_STATE_IN_COLLISION

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, collision, baxter

Recently I'm using Baxter Robot for a project. I ran the following ROS command:

```
roslaunch baxter_moveit_config demo_baxter.launch
```

and it took me a long time and I encounterd a few erros and warnings until it shows:

```
[ INFO] [1692680942.168522132, 2044.453000000]: Starting planning scene monitor
[ INFO] [1692680942.214501820, 2044.456000000]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1692680943.720781748, 2044.906000000]: waitForService: Service [/get_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1692680948.746332624, 2046.190000000]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[ INFO] [1692680948.746755222, 2046.190000000]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'both_arms' in namespace ''
[ WARN] [1692680952.649701742, 2046.958000000]: Waiting for /robot/limb/right/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1692680978.815528292, 2051.616000000]: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (30s)
[ WARN] [1692680986.208615426, 2052.958000000]: Waiting for /robot/limb/right/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1692681020.355613394, 2058.959000000]: Action client not connected: /robot/limb/right/follow_joint_trajectory
[ WARN] [1692681051.996243824, 2064.028000000]: Waiting for /robot/limb/left/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ WARN] [1692681086.208822138, 2070.028000000]: Waiting for /robot/limb/left/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1692681113.115083121, 2076.032000000]: Action client not connected: /robot/limb/left/follow_joint_trajectory
[ INFO] [1692681113.165033302, 2076.038000000]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1692681113.221697642, 2076.043000000]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[ INFO] [1692681113.221767538, 2076.043000000]: MoveGroup debug mode is OFF
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[ INFO] [1692681113.611576746, 2076.072000000]: 

********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1692681113.612904230, 2076.072000000]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1692681113.613070328, 2076.072000000]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

You can start planning now!
```

In the `Rviz` app. I dragged the arm of Baxter and clicked `Plan` Button, but below it shows  `failed`, and here's the screenshot.
[image]

You can see the gripper is red, and here's my bug:

```
[ INFO] [1692681982.542621081, 2234.252000000]: Start state appears to be in collision with respect to group both_arms
[ WARN] [1692681982.692952675, 2234.266000000]: Unable to find a valid state nearby the start state (using jiggle fraction of 0.050000 and 100 sampling attempts).
[ WARN] [1692681982.715335365, 2234.269000000]: Fail: ABORTED: START_STATE_IN_COLLISION
[ INFO] [1692681983.966597450, 2234.491000000]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[ INFO] [1692681983.966873204, 2234.491000000]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1692681983.967034677, 2234.491000000]: Starting state is just outside bounds (joint 'left_s1'). Assuming within bounds.
[ INFO] [1692681983.967049163, 2234.491000000]: Starting state is just outside bounds (joint 'right_s1'). Assuming within bounds.
[ INFO] [1692681983.967396741, 2234.491000000]: Found a contact between 'r_gripper_r_finger' (type 'Robot link') and 'r_gripper_r_finger_tip' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.
[ INFO] [1692681983.967415139, 2234.491000000]: Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 0 contacts are stored)
[ INFO] [1692681983.967453865, 2234.491000000]: Start state appears to be in collision with respect to group both_arms
[ WARN] [1692681984.154672860, 2234.516000000]: Unable to find a valid state nearby the start state (using jiggle fraction of 0.050000 and 100 sampling attempts).
[ INFO] [1692681984.192077706, 2234.519000000]: ABORTED: START_STATE_IN_COLLISION
```

I searched the Github and Stackoverflow but yet I haven't find similar bugs.

I'm earning for someone to solve this problem because I ought to hand in my robot project early this September.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The error says that the start state of the robot arm is in collision. This is why the trajectory planner is unable to generate a trajectory. Please update the start state and try again.

Comment: Thanks so much!! And by the way, could you please tell me how to set the start state? I'm a very beginner in ROS(sorry for bothering

Comment: In the RViz screenshot, I can see that the "Start State" and "Goal State" are set to <current>. Only for simulation purposes, I suggest changing them to random-valid (something similar should be there in the drop-down menu). It is worth going through the MoveIt documentation. Lastly, you can check out the following package as well: [baxter_moveit_tutorial](https://github.com/ravijo/baxter_moveit_tutorial)

Comment: In the drop-down menu I set `start state` to `random valid` and `left state` to `left_neural`, with planning group set to `left group`, but I still got the same output.     by the way, in rviz the gripper is marked in red color, I wonder if this is the problem of the gripper.   Thank you:)

Comment: I'm still unable to fix this, looking forward to your help:)

Answer (score 1):

In your log there is this line:

```
[ INFO] [1692681983.967396741, 2234.491000000]: Found a contact between 'r_gripper_r_finger' (type 'Robot link') and 'r_gripper_r_finger_tip' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored
```

You can disable this collision by updating the SRDF of your robot, adding something like this:

```
<disable_collisions link1="r_gripper_r_finger" link2="r_gripper_r_finger_tip" reason="Adjacent" />
```

That should solve your start state and allow you to plan

Comment: Thank you so much!!